# overload index action in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, overloading

I'm working on a multi language web site and I need to set language first and then shows the page in that exact language using Resources files.

I used two index action like this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Globalization;
using global_vrf.GeoIpService;

 namespace global_vrf.Controllers
  {
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
       public ActionResult Index(string language)
    {


        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Index() 
    {
        string language="en-us";

        return View(language);


    }


  }
}
```

but when I run the page, I have this Error:

> The current request for action 'Index' on controller type
>   'HomeController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(System.String) on type
>   global_vrf.Controllers.HomeController System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   Index() on type global_vrf.Controllers.HomeController

Comment: this occurs because you have same name action methods. To avoid this you have to use [HTTPGet] and [HTTPPost] before each methods.

Comment: Delete the 2nd method. in the first method, if the value of `language` is `null`, the set it to `"en-us"`

Comment: @StephenMueckethank you so much, teo van kot suggested the same and that works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make one method:

```
 namespace global_vrf.Controllers
 {
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
       public ActionResult Index(string language)
       {
          if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(language))
          {
             string language="en-us";
          }
          Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
          Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);

          return View();
       }
    }
 }
```

You can't make 2 methods becouse `string` could be null.

Comment: thanks good idea, Im working on it and I will let you know if this works

Answer (score 1):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string language)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);

    return View();
}

[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index() 
    {
        string language="en-us";

        return View(language);


    }
```

Comment: thanks for your care, the error changed to `The view 'en-us' or its master was not found` I think I need to make some changes also in this line `return View(language);`

Comment: in your view you have to use @model string as the first line. I think that you already have the view

Comment: Yes I have a simple View, nothing important on it, no difference, I meant I need something like this `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { language = language });`